# How to use laravel localization on database fetched records?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization

Basically we can localize the `strings` in the application using `trans()` method after making an array in `lang` directory. But that is kind of hard coding. For example, if we want to translate a message. we would do something like this.

```
/resources
  /lang
    /en
      messages.php
    /es
      messages.php
```

and then we make an array and hard code it. just like

```
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];
```

But what if data is coming from `database`? we do not know how many records are coming and what is in the `database`. For example, we have an articles and we want to translate its `title` to other language say to `French`. How can we accomplish this without any `package` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Laravel translation manager from barryvdh.

This is a package to manage Laravel translation files. It does not replace the Translation system, only import/export the php files to a database and make them editable through a webinterface. The workflow would be:

- Import translations: Read all translation files and save them in the database
- Find all translations in php/twig sources
- Optionally: Listen to missing translation with the custom Translator
- Translate all keys through the webinterface
- Export: Write all translations back to the translation files.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

Comment: i am kind of confused. Will it translate the data coming from database? For example, title is `something from database` now i dont know what is coming. I just clicked on `French link` and then this `package` changed the text title text to `French version` of `something from database`

Comment: @QasimAli this will get all the default translations from (for example english) and store them temporary in the database. When you're done with editing you can let Laravel concert it to the default files.

Comment: This answer doesn't solves the problem of localizing column of a database records, in this case 'title' .
First of all you need to store title in multiple languages in different column, may be like title_en, title_fr etc. 
Then need some kind code in model to switch column based on app locale

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store title in multiple languages in different column, may be like title_en, title_fr etc.

if you use Eloquent, you can add to your model:

```
public function getTitle() {
   $locale = App::getLocale() ?: 'en';
   return $this->{'title_'.$locale};
}
```

if not, via Query Builder:

```
 $locale = App::getLocale() ?: 'en';
 DB::table('categories')->select('id', 'title_'.$locale.' as title')->get();
```